# Fetch specific string based on pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column with data like {"Type":1,"ApplicationID":1,} or

```
{"Type":1,"ApplicationID":158,} 
or 
{"Type":1,"ApplicationID":234,"TarifType":1,"TarifID":2} or  etc.
```

I tried with

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%"ApplicationID":___,%', '{"Type":1,"ApplicationID":177,}') 
or
SELECT PATINDEX('%"ApplicationID":[0-9][0-9][0-9],%', '{"Type":1,"ApplicationID":177,}')
```

to fetch the index of expression it returns a value.

But the problem is the application id can be any number from 1 to int (max) so we cannot fix the number of integer chars as it is in above queries.

If i can find the correct path index than, I might be able to find the substring later.

Is there any way to do this? I need to use the application ID in subquery or cor-related query. Otherwise we can store it in some temp table.

Please suggest a way to fetch this id.

Comment: Thanks John for formating.

Comment: what is data type of that column ?

Comment: Data type is nvarchar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If **NOT** 2016

Just for fun, and perhaps overkill, you can convert your JSON string into XML, and then extact desired values/attributes.

I added an additional `replace(JSON_String,',}','}')` to trap the malformed JSON string.  Can be removed if sample data was a typo.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (ID int,JSON_String varchar(max))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'{"Type":1,"ApplicationID":1,}')
,(2,'{"Type":1,"ApplicationID":158,}')
,(3,'{"Type":1,"ApplicationID":234,"TarifType":1,"TarifID":2}')

Select A.ID
      ,[Type]          = XMLData.value('(row/@Type)[1]'         , 'int') 
      ,[ApplicationID] = XMLData.value('(row/@ApplicationID)[1]', 'int') 
      ,[TarifID]       = XMLData.value('(row/@TarifID)[1]'      , 'int') 
 From  @YourTable  A
 Cross Apply (values (convert(xml,replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(JSON_String,',}','}'),'"',''),'{','<row '),'}','"/>'),':','="'),',','" ')))
             ) B (XMLData)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. We are using SQL 2014 and it worked. SQL 2016 JSON functions are not available.

Comment: @VaibhavSharma Happy it helped

Comment: @VaibhavSharma Just a side note, since you are 2014, I would recommend try_convert(xml, --- ) rather than convert(xml, --- ).  This will return a null just in case your (presumably) simple JSON string is not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just look for the keyword?

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%"ApplicationID":%', '{"Type":1,"ApplicationID":177,}')
```

I don't see a need to match the value, just the keyword, especially given that the keyword is already in double quotes.

Also, I should point out that to get a match to values that have that keyword, use `LIKE`:

```
WHERE col LIKE '%"ApplicationID":%'
```

Comment: yes, Gordorn it can be done. Actually, I was trying to fetch the value part so I was a bit experimenting which went wrongly. I can find the initial index. But stuck with the finding the value.    Tried SELECT SUBSTRING('{"Type":1,"ApplicationID":177,}', PATINDEX('%"ApplicationID":%', '{"Type":1,"ApplicationID":177,}') +16, LEN('{"Type":1,"ApplicationID":177,}')) to get data but it gives the end comma. Actually it shall give a more lengthy string based on the length of data being worked upon

Comment: @VaibhavSharma . . . If you are using SQL Server 2016, you should investigate the JSON functions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-functions-transact-sql).  If you are using SQL Server and JSON and not using 2016, then consider upgrading.